# Setting "WindowsState"="Maximized" in Style doesn't work after manual minimize/restore

Tags: wpf, window, windows-10

My `Window` has a `DataTrigger` that looks like this:

```
 <Window.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFullscreen}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="WindowState" Value="Maximized" />
                    <!-- Other setters -->
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFullscreen}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="WindowState" Value="Normal" />
                    <!-- Other setters -->
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>
```

This works just fine until the user minimizes and restores the window (e.g. by clicking the _ button followed by the taskbar icon). The effects of the other setters continue to evidence after this when `IsFullscreen` changes, so I know the trigger continues to fire; the problem is that the `WindowState` setting is no longer heeded. Removing the other setters doesn't fix this, so they're not to blame. What's going on? What can I do to fix it?

Problem is occurring on a Windows 10 PC; no info about what happens with a different OS.

Comment: Did you try to bind the property directly?

Comment: @JanDotNet I hadn't due to the other things the trigger needs to do (the setters I edited out), but I tried it and it has the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since dependency properties might be set in different places a precedence list is needed. You can find this list [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx).

When you minimize your window by clicking the corresponding button, you are setting the **local value** of the `WindowState` dependecy property. As per the precedence list we saw before, your `DataTrigger` can't work anymore.

Comment: In support of this explanation, I tried using an attached behavior to set `WindowState` from code instead of from a style or binding, and that works consistently.